# Using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound - Shuts off Audiobooks and Podcasts in background

Tags: ios

I am using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` to play short sounds in my app.  It works great, except when people want to listen to their podcasts or audio books in the background while playing they can't.  When they launch the game, their sound shuts off.

Comment: So... What's the question then?

Comment: i want them to be able to listen to their background sound.  I can't figure out why the app is causing their sound to shut down.